# How to print customized barcode labels

Tags: c#, barcode

I have a windows application which is responsible for printing customized barcode labels roll based on user's needs like specifying the texts, dimensions and size.
The user will use Zepra and TSC barcode printers, I just need to know how to let the user choose determine the size of label and the space between labels and also the all margins (top, right, bottom and left).
I need a code-snippet does that in C# and the final result to be like [this](http://www.bluelinelabels.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/bar-code-roll-label-3-e1460149552698-300x300.jpg).

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For Zebra part:

Here is an example how to send ZPL commands into printer:
https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA301&cat=ZISV_PL_ZPL&actp=LIST

Here you can find pdf document from ZPL commands which are send to printer. Build a suitable set of codes which will produce the label and barcode that you need:
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mino for your kind efforts, but it didn't help me well. Earlier, I saw a code-snippet uses the **PrintDocument** object and send the drawn object to the printer after specifying the margins, vertical and horizontal spaces and the texts (barcode symbol, price and product name), but I can't remember where I saw it. 

Kindly check [this](http://www.aulux.com/support/barcodelabelmaker7/images/labelsetup.png) and [this](http://www.capturebites.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Bar-Code-Generator-Layout.png).
This is what I exactly want to do.